# Python-social-auth pipeline returns TypeError when I'm trying to get access_token

Tags: python, django, google-plus, python-social-auth

I have custom pipeline in my django project. Following [this example](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/use_cases.html#retrieve-google-friends) I'm trying to get access token (to get data from google plus) but it returns me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Custom pipeline:

```
def user_details(strategy, details, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ....

    if user:
        if kwargs['is_new']:
            if "google" in kwargs['backend'].redirect_uri:
                ...
                try:
                    social = user.social_auth.get(provider='google-plus')
                    access_token = logger.warning(social.extra_data['access_token'])
                    ....

                except HTTPError:
                    pass
                .....
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py", line 51, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py", line 28, in complete
    redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/actions.py", line 43, in do_complete
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 41, in complete
    return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/utils.py", line 229, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/backends/google.py", line 158, in auth_complete
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/utils.py", line 229, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py", line 398, in do_auth
    return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/strategies/django_strategy.py", line 96, in authenticate
    return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 74, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 82, in authenticate
    return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 85, in pipeline
    out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/linevich/.virtualenvs/tathros/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 112, in run_pipeline
    result = func(*args, **out) or {}
  File "/home/linevich/projects/tathros/proto/pipeline.py", line 54, in user_details
    auth_token = social.extra_data['access_token']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: can you show the value of `repr(social.extra_data)`? It seems to be a `str`..

Comment: `'{"code": null, "access_token": "ya29..ygKZMLlldKN5jJM3UE9zkgMkcX9Gd3Qx1yzvnskn7C4RfrhDBNhYI974_bmGKdYgDd45zjqEYnI", "expires": 3599, "user_id": "113965887663380153252"}'`

Comment: is that from `print(repr(social.extra_data))` or just the `repr(..)` entered into a console?  If it was printed then it seems to be a string that is a valid `dict` literal which is odd, and if it is the result of the console then it is definitely a `dict` which means the error makes no sense... something is very odd about this...

Comment: I've already found the solution, it returns JSON in string (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutuion was simple:

```
auth_token = json.loads(social.extra_data)['access_token']
```